# Retrieve Data from the database and set in custom listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

Retrieve Data from the database and set in custom listview but only show the last data from DB in list view.

this is my code please solve my problem.

```
SQLiteDatabase myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_Name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
try {
    c=myDb.rawQuery("select sid,name,num from Contact", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).toString();
            num1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("num")).toString();
            Log.d("string is",name1+num1);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    valnumber.add(name1+"<<"+num1+">>");
    custlistAdapter = new CustListview(Contact.this, R.layout.custlistview,valnumber);
    ShowCont.setAdapter(custlistAdapter);
    myDb.close();
```

**CustListview.java**

public class CustListview extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> web;
 int layoutResourceId;
public CustListview(Activity context,int custlistview, List<String> val)
{
super(context, R.layout.custlistview, val);
this.context = context;
this.web = (ArrayList<String>) val;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View Convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
View row=Convertview;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custlistview, null, true);
        holder=new UserHolder();
        holder.imgdelete=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.imagedelete);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        //View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custlistview, null, true);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else    
        {
    holder=(UserHolder)row.getTag();
        }            
    holder.txtTitle.setText(web.toString());
    holder.imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
return row;
}
static class UserHolder {
     TextView txtTitle;
     Button imgdelete;
 }}
```

Comment: Logic error. Move valnumber.add(name1+"<<"+num1+">>"); in while loop.

Comment: i try this also but same last data are show.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like that

```
cursor = sqldb.query("Contact", null, null, null, null, null, "sid");
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do { 
            name1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    num1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("num"));
                    Log.d("string is",name1+num1);
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: i want to add this db data in custom list..
i add 3 line in before while statement. same this shows only last data in list view. 
valnumber.add(name1+"<<"+num1+">>");
    custlistAdapter = new CustListview(Contact.this, R.layout.custlistview,valnumber);
   ShowCont.setAdapter(custlistAdapter); //listview

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how many names and number you are getting from the database. 
Your code was only adding one row in the array which you have to move inside the while loop.

```
SQLiteDatabase myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_Name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
try {
    c=myDb.rawQuery("select sid,name,num from Contact", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            num1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("num"));
            Log.d("string is",name1+num1);
           valnumber.add(name1+"<<"+num1+">>");

        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    custlistAdapter = new CustListview(Contact.this, R.layout.custlistview,valnumber);
    ShowCont.setAdapter(custlistAdapter);
    myDb.close();
```